# Protect WCF from fiddler (MITM) (PCL XAMARIN FORMS)

Tags: wcf, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, basichttpbinding

I have xamarin forms project using portable class library.
In that PCL I reference my WCF service which is hosted in some server.

The wcf binding is Basichttpbinding with security transport as PCL does not support wshttpbinding.

Also the wcf is use https and i have a valid certificate for that.

*I want to secure the messages because now if i install some kind of application fiddler or packed monitor in my android every call to my service i can see the xml data in readable format.*

I thought by using https i was protecting that. 
I try use wcf TransportWithMessageCredential but it failed to login to my service because xamarin does not yet support this combination

So: ( after research i found out that )

- PCL does not support wshttpbinding only basicHttpBinding
- Xamarin.Forms basicHttpBinding does not support message security but  only
  TransportCredentialOnly

And

- Xamarin does not support TransportWithMessageCredential but only
  transport security but transport security  not protecting the data from MITM.

How others working with xamarin forms and protect these data?
Do i missed anything?
Any suggestions?

**EDITED**

---

I am trying to encrypt the **xml request** before send to service but fails every time i change the message e.g from xml to encoded characters (i guess because the server fails to recognize the schema )

I have implement **IClientMessageInspector** at the client Side as also **IDispatchMessageInspector** at the server side.

I need some help how i can send the xml request encrypted to the server.. if i do it here then i can decode it from service side ( server)

At the client side i have the following

```
  Public Function BeforeSendRequest(ByRef request As Message, channel As IClientChannel) As Object Implements IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest

    Dim Binding As New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport)

    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptedData(request.ToString)))

    Dim RQuotas As Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas = Binding.ReaderQuotas

    Dim reader = Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(ms, RQuotas)
    request = Message.CreateMessage(reader, Int32.MaxValue, request.Version)


    Return Nothing

End Function
```

I am not sure if i do it correctly. Any help welcome.

Comment: Why not make a restful webapi that calls your wcf service and then use that webapi from your mobile app?

Comment: Your statement that basicHttpBinding does not support message security is not correct. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-security-sample)[ms doc]

Comment: in xamarin.Forms BasicHttpBinding supports only TransportCredentialOnly . I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler only decrypts Https Traffic if you accept its certificate, it basically acts a man in the middle and handles all the calls from the service to your app, there is  some useful info here https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS ,

[image: Fiddler Https Decryption]

---

On your second update of the question, you would need to create a container that will house all your messages, 
that way you can decrypt and encrypt the data as you see fit,

A simple example can be found at https://misaxionsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/secure-restful-web-service-by-wcf-web-api-no-https-seriously/

You can customise it as much as possible

Here is the message that is defined in the link above

**Message**

```
public class Message
{
    public string AppId { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public byte[] GenerateFingerprint();

    public bool ValidateHash(byte[] fingerprint);
}
```

**Encrypted Message**

```
public class EncryptedMessage
{
    public string AppId { get; set; }

    public byte[] Fingerprint { get; set; }

    ///<summary>
    /// The 3DES key used to encrypt/decrypt the message 
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] Key { get; set; }

    ///<summary>
    /// Encrypted message
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] Message { get; set; }
}
```

**IEncryptionHelper**

```
public interface IEncryptionHelper
{
    EncryptedMessage Encrypt(Message message);

    Message Decrypt(EncryptedMessage encryptedMessage);
}
```

Comment: This is what i want to protect. But the combination of WCF,PCL,XAMARIN not allow me to use fully the security features ( at least what i know ) and now by stack on this...i ask if there is any workaround

Comment: If you dont trust the certificate, it can decrypt it, simple as that, if you are looking for something different then, you would need to encrypt the info on the service and decrypt it on your side using on of the many crypto algorithms

Comment: A simple look at [https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/how-safe-is-ssl](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/how-safe-is-ssl) should give you the info on how secure SSL is.

Comment: Am sorry but am still confused how to prevent this: e.g someone install my android app on his mobile, after install fiddler, and then start working my app, then of course if he will check the fiddler he will see my xml structure and data from my service responses.. how then is protected..? how can you protect this?

Comment: In fiddler he would need to install the certificate, that I have already said, if you dont want him to guess your structure, then take the whole data you are sending to the service, and encrypt it, then decrypt it on the client side, even if fiddler is installed, he wont see anything

Comment: can you provide me with some samples how to encrypt and decrypt the data in both? client and server side?

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) Show you how to use AES, you would need the same key on the client and server side to decrypt the data

Comment: I have edited the question if you could help me a little bit more. because i try to implement your suggestion (encrypt the whole data "xml")

Comment: You can try this link [https://misaxionsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/secure-restful-web-service-by-wcf-web-api-no-https-seriously/](https://misaxionsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/secure-restful-web-service-by-wcf-web-api-no-https-seriously/) on how to create a custom message that doesnt show your structure.